# Can I convert a .clang-format file to the Eclipse formatter format?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, clang-format, autoformatting, format-conversion

I'm using Eclipse CDT to work on a repository which has a .clang-format file, and would like to use it. So - can I somehow convert it into the XML format which the Eclipse formatter uses?

Note: The reverse direction is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63373842/1593077).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest solution is not to use Eclipse CDT.
Here you can find a simple extension that will use clang format https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cppstyle